# How do I do string replace for xml nodes using simpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, str-replace

I was wondering if you could help. The code below pulls in XML data from an external XML file and then re-formats it into table data. All works perfect. However, some of the data from the XML file needs to be changed and so is it possible to use str_replace or preg_replace for each individual node below? I do not know how to write the str_replace for each node. I thought perhaps something like this "**{$hour->weatherCod} . str_replace (10, Sun);**" would work but it doesn't. Would smeone be able to tell me the correct format? I need something easy as I am more of an actionscript guy rather than php.

Many thanks if youre able to help!

```
<?php
// load SimpleXML
$data = new SimpleXMLElement('xml_file.xml', null, true);
foreach($data->weather as $weather)
{
foreach ($weather->hourly as $hour)
{
echo <<<EOF
    <tr>
            <td>{$weather->day}</td>
            <td>{$weather->Ctemp1}&deg;c</td>
            <td>{$weather->Ctemp2}&deg;c</td>
            <td>{$hour->time}</td>
            <td>{$hour->tempC}&deg;c</td>
            <td>{$hour->tempF}&deg;f</td>
            <td>{$hour->windMiles}mph</td>
            <td>{$hour->windKmph}km/h</td>
            <td>{$hour->windDegree}&deg;</td>
            <td>{$hour->winddir}</td>
            <td>{$hour->weatherCod}</td>            
            <td>{$hour->weatherIconUrl}</td>
            <td>{$hour->precipMM}mm</td>
            <td>{$hour->humidity}%</td>
            <td>{$hour->visibility}</td>
            <td>{$hour->pressure}mb</td>
            <td>{$hour->cloudcover}</td>
            <td>{$hour->sigHeight_m}m</td>
            <td>{$hour->swellHeight_m}m</td>
            <td>{$hour->swellDir}&deg;</td>
            <td>{$hour->swellPeriod_secs}s</td>
            <td>{$hour->waterTemp_C}&deg;c</td>
            <td>{$hour->waterTemp_F}&deg;f</td>
    </tr>
EOF;
}
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, I didn't get it yet. What exactly should be replaced by what exactly? Pls show a snippet of your XML.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you try to do with {$hour->weatherCod} . str_replace (10, Sun); ?

Look how it works, it takes 3 parameters not 2. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

So may by something like this

```
str_replace (10, Sun, $hour->weatherCod);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. So would my code look like(?): <td>{$hour->weatherCod}</td>str_replace (10, Sun, $hour->weatherCod);

Comment: It should work, i have same thing but with preg_replace because i need regular expression. But you need to put parameter that you need as 3rd argument to str_replace, because i just put something from your example.

Comment: No, that didnt work. It just printed it all out on the page: "str_replace (10, Sun, 10);"

Comment: Actually you need to put it in <?php your code here ?>, And what is Sun? Is it variable or text or const? Because if it text it should be in quotes!

Comment: The whole code above which i originally posted is already in php brackets and yet Sun is text. Regardless, it still doesn't work so does anyone else have a suggestion?

Comment: You put function in text that`s why you see str_replace (10, Sun, 10); You need to put it as a function.

Comment: Ok but that was my original question. Exactly how it should be writtne because everything i have tried doesnt work.

Comment: Put it in to curly brackets {}, or `EOF . str_replace (10, Sun, 10) . echo ...`. You can read here http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php how to work with strings.

Comment: Yeah thanks. To be honest, I have already pretty much written the correct reply to my own question except I do not have the correct formatting to make it work. Im not reading all through the link you just posted. If no one can help properly ill just pay someone to fix it.